# What name does this type of people have?

Tags: word-request

If there's a name for the plastic band of shoelaces, a name for this should exist.

When I get into a new (public) place for first time and I know I'll return there a lot of times, I choose a site (that site is ever the same) where I put my things, and I never move my items to another place like normal people do. 
I do it constantly, like in the locker room of a swimming pool or of my school, I have a special place where to put my things.

In bars, I do the same, and in parks too (and at a lot of places also I do it).

*Does it have a special name? What name does the person who does that get?*

Comment: Sheldony? "You're in my spot."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for a medical term, [Obsessive-compulsive disorder (OCD)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsessive%E2%80%93compulsive_disorder) or [Obsessive-compulsive personality disorder (OCPD)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsessive%E2%80%93compulsive_personality_disorder) come to mind, describing a psychological conditition that *forces* the suffer to repeat actions or execute actions in a ritualized way.

A non-medical term, especially if you *like* things happening in always the same way or order, you would be a [creature of habit](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/worterbuch/englisch/creature-of-habit).

Comment: I don't think the original post suggests disordered behavior. The tendency is quite natural.